# buildout + django-timezones 0.2.dev2?

Tags: django, buildout

I'm trying to install django-timezones 0.2.dev2 over buildout, but no matter which setup I add, it still keeps downloading version 0.1.4.

I have tried using a git recipe, and also other recipes trying to get the tar.gz directly, like this:

```
[django-timezones]
recipe =  hexagonit.recipe.download
url = http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/d/django-timezones-op/django-timezones-op-0.2.dev2.tar.gz
md5sum = ad877b180b13759bc252dc2c0579a90e
```

Is there a way to get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pin the version in a versions section:

```
[buildout]
parts =
    django-timezones
    ....
versions = versions
....

[versions]
django-timezones = 0.2.dev2
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked! I already had the version under versions, but the  issue was that I was adding django-timezones under "eggs" rather than under "parts".

Comment: Great things worked :-) Could you click the 'accept' link to mark the answer as the correct one?